# Should IAsyncEnumerator<T>.DisposeAsync() throw if the last MoveNextAsync() task is not awaited?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, async-await, iasyncenumerable

Why does the `UseEventsFail` throw in the code below? Could it be that I dispose the async enumerator without awaiting the last `MoveNextAsync()` task? This example is simplified repro of my real program, so I need to dispose the async enumerator to release its resources. And `Task.CompletedTask` is usually a `Task.Delay()` used as a timeout for `UseEvents()`. If the enumerator task completes before the timeout task, then no exception is thrown.

Stack trace of exception:

`at Program.<<<Main>$>g__GenerateEvents|0_3>d.System.IAsyncDisposable.DisposeAsync()`

Code:

```cs
// All these are ok
await GenerateEvents().GetAsyncEnumerator().DisposeAsync();
await using var enu = GenerateEvents().GetAsyncEnumerator();
await UseEvents();
await UseEvents2();

// This fail
await UseEventsFail();

async Task UseEvents()
{
    await using var enu = GenerateEvents().GetAsyncEnumerator();
    await Task.WhenAny(enu.MoveNextAsync().AsTask());
}

async Task UseEvents2()
{
    var enu = GenerateEvents().GetAsyncEnumerator();
    await Task.WhenAny(enu.MoveNextAsync().AsTask(), Task.CompletedTask);
}

async Task UseEventsFail()
{
    await using var enu = GenerateEvents().GetAsyncEnumerator();
    await Task.WhenAny(enu.MoveNextAsync().AsTask(), Task.CompletedTask);
}

async IAsyncEnumerable<bool> GenerateEvents()
{
    while (true) {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        yield return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the MSDN article [Iterating with Async Enumerables in C# 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/november/csharp-iterating-with-async-enumerables-in-csharp-8#much-ado-about-threading) by Stephen Toub:

> It should be evident that it’s fine for one `MoveNextAsync` call to occur on a different thread from a previous or subsequent `MoveNextAsync` call; after all, the implementation may await a task and continue execution somewhere else. However, that doesn’t mean `MoveNextAsync` is “thread-safe”—far from it. On a given async enumerator, `MoveNextAsync` must never be invoked concurrently, meaning `MoveNextAsync` shouldn’t be called again on a given enumerator until the previous call to it has completed. Similarly, `DisposeAsync` on an iterator shouldn’t be invoked while either `MoveNextAsync` or `DisposeAsync` on that same enumerator is still in flight.

So, no, `IAsyncEnumerator<T>`s do not support concurrency. The same is true for `IEnumerator<T>`s. You can't call `Dispose` from one thread while a `MoveNext` is running on another thread. Enumerating in general (synchronously or asynchronously) is not a thread-safe procedure, and must be synchronized.

Comment: ahh, nice find :)

Comment: So I assume cancellation is the only option to properly dispose am IAsyncEnumerable. That is, supply a cancellation token to GetEnumerator(), have the async iterator be cancellable ([EnumeratorCancellation]). Then on timout cancel the iterator, await Task.WhenAny(lastMoveNextAsyncTask), then call await DisposeAsync()

Comment: @maloo yeap, pretty much that's it.

Comment: **Bottom line**
*"Enumerating in general (synchronously or asynchronously) is not a thread-safe procedure, and must be synchronized."*